# Comparing Two different Data frames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and struggling get a solution for the following problem. I have two data frames, let's say `current_df` and `old_df`. The columns of both the data frames are common but the length may vary. To explain the problem in further detail lets assume the columns to be - `Name, Id, Salary, Work_hours, Location, Date_updated`. I want to compare the data frames based on the `Date_updated`(it is a datetime object),

1. if the `Date_updated` of the `current_df` is different than that of `old_df`, then compare the values of `Salary, Work_hours, Location` of both the data frames and if there is any change in any of the values then I should get old value of the changed parameter and new value of the same parameter.
2. if there is no change in the other parameters then leave it as it is

Below is the explaination for the same using a code

```
columns = ['Name', 'Id', 'Salary', 'Work_hours', 'Location', 'Date_updated']

old_data = [
    ['John', 1, 1000, 100, 'York', '2013-01-01'],
    ['Tim', 2, 1500, 210, 'Chicago', '2013-04-03'],
    ['Rob', 3, 900, 180, 'San Francisco', '2013-02-07'],
    ['Tom', 4, 2000, 220, 'New York', '2013-01-01'],
    ['Steve', 5, 1200, 190, 'Chicago', '2013-06-01'],
    ['Jim', 6, 1000, 170, 'New York', '2013-01-01'],
    ['Mark', 7, 1500, 210, 'Chicago', '2013-04-03'],
    ['John', 8, 900, 180, 'San Francisco', '2013-02-07'],
]


new_data = [
    ['John', 1, 2000, 200, 'New York', '2014-01-01'],
    ['Tim', 2, 1000, 300, 'Miami', '2014-04-03'],
    ['Rob', 9, 900, 180, 'San Francisco', '2016-02-07'],  # new employee
]


df_old = pd.DataFrame(data=old_data, columns=columns).set_index('Id').sort_index()

df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=new_data, columns=columns).set_index('Id').sort_index()
```

In the above code,
Johns `Salary` changed from 1000 too 2000 as well as `Work_hours` changed from 100 to 200. Similarly Rob's data also got upadeted. I am trying to display those parameters, it can be in a list or a data frame row or anything.
One example of the output can be

```
>> Following employee's data was updated
#Ignoring the Time_updated
>> Old data : ['John', 1, 1000, 100, 'York', '2013-01-01']
   New data : ['John', 1, 2000, 200, 'New York', '2014-01-01']
   Parameters updated : Salary, Working_hours, Location

>> Old data : ['Tim', 2, 1500, 210, 'Chicago', '2013-04-03']
   New data : ['Tim', 2, 1000, 300, 'Miami', '2014-04-03']
   Parameters updated : Salary, Working_hours, Location
```

I want the `Name` and `Id` of the employee along with the changed parameter and it's old and new values.

I tried the same logic using for loops but then realised it will take hours to get the output and its a very un-optimal way of doing things. I would be very grateful if someone please suggest a way to get this task done using any in-built pandas functions.
Thank you.

**Note: `Name` and `Id` both together will serve as the primary key. There can be duplication in `Id` which I can't eliminate according to the requirement of the task.**

Comment: can you explain "then I should get old value of the changed parameter and new value of the same parameter." ?

Comment: You can use pandas `join` (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) using, for example, `how='outer'` and then apply your logic. 
p.s it would be helpful if you provide inputs and expected outputs

Comment: @parisni I have updated the post and added the examples

Comment: @TomRon I have provided the inputs and the expected outputs